# TinyMCE URLs (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce

I got a problem with the URLs in TinyMCE. Everything works just fine until I try to open a plugin dialog (for example clicking the emotions icon), then I get the following errors:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "http://localhost:55414/Resources/Script/themes/advanced/skins/default/dialog.css"*

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"http://localhost:55414/Controls/General/TinyMCE/Controls/General/TinyMCE/plugins/emotions/langs/en_dlg.js"

tiny_mce.js is located in Resources/Script/ and the rest of the files are located in Controls/General/TinyMCE/. The URL settings are the following:

```
tinyMCE.baseURL = "../../Controls/General/TinyMCE";
convert_urls: false,
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false
```

Apparently I am doing something wrong with the URLs. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php) showing different configurable url options.